# Accessing an Eager loaded navigation property causes lazy load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a `Navigation Property` which is `Eager Loaded` inside a `using` statement. Now, in my view when I try to access that property for an non-existent `FK`(f.e. -1 or deleted row in master table), `EF` tries to lazy load it and fails, since the context was already disposed. Is there anything I can do to prevent this exception? The first option is catching it, the other is to turn off the `Lazy Loading` and maybe the `Proxy Creation` in the same occasion...but are there any other options or checks that could be preformed?

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Post post;
    using (var db = new BlogDbContext())
    {
        post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id)
            .Include(p => p.Comments.Select(c => c.Author))
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }
    if (post == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return PartialView(post);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the (relevant portion of the) `using` block where the retrieval is being done?

Comment: @CraigW. Sure, it's really straightforward...

Comment: I wonder if the fact you're doing a `.Select` inside the `.Include` is messing you up. I think you might be returning an `iQueryable` as the nested property which won't resolve until you dereference it later (in your view). Try adding a `.ToList` to that (i.e. `p.Comments.Select(c => c.Author).ToList()`) or remove the `.Select` and return the whole `Comment` object just as a test.